# Как сменить иконку пункта меню при загрузке Activity и проверке массива?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, меню

Есть код для добавления позиции в массив:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        TextView cntContent = findViewById(R.id.cntContent);

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.favoriteNone:

                Intent giveIntent = getIntent();
                contentUrl = giveIntent.getStringExtra("URL_KEY");
                contentTitle = giveIntent.getStringExtra("TITLE_KEY");
                contentDate = giveIntent.getStringExtra("DATE_KEY");
                contentCategory = giveIntent.getStringExtra("CATEGORY_KEY");

                for(NewsClass urls : Favorites.favoritNews) {
                    if (urls.getmUrl().contains(contentUrl)) {
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favdark);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Уже есть в избранном", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                Favorites.favoritNews.add(new NewsClass(
                        contentTitle,
                        contentDate,
                        contentUrl,
                        contentCategory
                        ));

                TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(this);
                tinyDB.clear();
                Gson gsonCreate = new Gson();
                ArrayList<String> gsonString = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i = 0; i < Favorites.favoritNews.size(); i++)
                    gsonString.add(gsonCreate.toJson(Favorites.favoritNews.get(i)));
                tinyDB.putListString("tinyFavoritNews",gsonString);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favdark);
                Intent favorites = new Intent(NewsContent.this, Favorites.class);
                startActivity(favorites);

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

В данном случае код `item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favdark);` работает как нужно, иконка меняется. Но когда я делаю проверку массива на совпадение и в случае оного пытаюсь сменить иконку, приложение крашится:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_content);
        Intent giveIntent = getIntent();
        contentUrl = giveIntent.getStringExtra("URL_KEY");
        contentTitle = giveIntent.getStringExtra("TITLE_KEY");
        contentDate = giveIntent.getStringExtra("DATE_KEY");
        contentCategory = giveIntent.getStringExtra("CATEGORY_KEY");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_content);
        MenuItem fav = findViewById(R.id.favoriteNone);
        for(NewsClass urls : Favorites.favoritNews) {
            if (urls.getmUrl().contains(contentUrl)) {
                fav.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favdark);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Уже есть в избранном", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

И крашится именно на строке `fav.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favdark);`, ссылаясь на
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference`

Как мне сменить иконку после проверки массива на совпадение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Инициализируем меню

```
private Menu menu;
```

Меняем onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_social, menu);
    return true;
}
```

И пишем в onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    MenuItem fav = menu.findItem(R.id.favoriteNone);
    for(NewsClass urls : Favorites.favoritNews) {
        if (urls.getmUrl().contains(contentUrl)) {
            fav.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_favdark));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно иначе:

```
private MenuItem itemMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate...

    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    // Получаете ссылку на пункт меню
    itemMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.item_menu);
    return true;
}
```

И в нужном месте:

```
itemMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_picture);
```